# Is it possible to integrate Datatables in Yii?

Tags: jquery, yii, datatables

Is it possible to integrate [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) in 
**yii framework**?  if so how it can be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude You actually don't need them...Yii comes with gridview which is exectly same function..

[Check Yii Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

Anyway if want to add, include its jquery files in yii/layouts/mail(or whichever you are using..)

Comment: datatable plugin jquery makes generation of pdf and csv easier... is der ny option  in YII like that...

Comment: There are extensions for that...But yeah those are not straight forward to use..:)